# How to enable CONFIG_SND_DEBUG for pcm debugging?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, alsa

I want to debug the `PCM`. but to do that I need to enable `CONFIG_SND_DEBUG=y` and `CONFIG_PCM_XRUN_DEBUG=y`. but I don't know how to enable this in Linux kernel.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a copy of the kernel's source and modify the `.config` file. This is located at the base directory of the source. From there you can use `make` to modify the configuration. The command `make menuconfig` will give you a nice UI to work around in, and search for your config option.